# Access controll list(ACL) in searchguard

Tags: elasticsearch, search-guard

Can I have the complete list of this acl:

```
indices:data/read*
```

for example:

```
indices:data/read/get
indices:data/read/mget
indices:data/read/search
indices:data/read/msearch
...
```

Best Regards.